# How to find available CiviCRM release versions?

Tags: system-status

we're working on a bash script to upgrade CiviCRM and we try to get a list of the available released version.

Use case is if you're running on for example 5.45 and want to upgrade then you could see all available options and maybe choose the version you want

Answer (score 1):

Sourceforge has an rss feed you can parse: https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/rss?path=/civicrm-stable

Or you can use the local cache which is updated by the version_check job and parse that: sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/version-msgs-cache.json

Comment: thanks Dave, the json file is a bit mixed up. but at least we have a path